Encounter an error while moving WSL from c disk to other one
I try to move the WSL from c disk to other one through cmd firstly, but got stuck for a long time at moving... prompt during import operation, then I quit the operation and try to rerun it and got the error below:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --import Ubuntu-20.04 D:\WSL D:\WSL\ubuntu2004.tar
Import in progress, this may take a few minutes.
A distribution with the supplied name already exists.
Error code: Wsl/Service/RegisterDistro/0x800700b7
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>

then I try to make it through app list portal but got error enter image description here
I expect the WSL can be moved from c disk to other one, and be able to bootup successfully and won't consume the c disk space.
